# Secret Santa sorting issue

Tags: php, sql, database

I was assigned the task of making a secret santa site where a user logs in and a random name is chosen from a database. The condition being that u don't draw your own name but since a single name is picked at a time, I ran into the below mentioned issue:
3 people are (bill,mike and jake)
bill < mike
Mike < bill
If mike and bill get each other, jake won't have a partner.
I could write a small piece of code that avoids this when coming down to a small number of people, I was wandering if their is anything else to get around this issue.
My current php code

```
$sql ="SELECT gifted 
        FROM gifts 
        WHERE gifted != '$username' 
        AND isgifted = 0 
        ORDER BY Rand() 
        LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: @ADyson Your wish is .... :)

Comment: So your PHP code is just a SQL query?

Comment: You'll need to makethe assignment all at once at the beginning. Otherwise some people will need to give get two+ presents while some others won't need to provide any gift at all.

Comment: @Andy 
yes that was one solution that came to mind but after looking into it for while i realized that method is also open for issues when four people are present. for example if A gets B,and B gets C and C gets A . D will have no one to gift even when no one is gifting each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a simple algorithm which solves this problem would be:

1. Get a list of all the participants, sorted in a random order with the SQL [rand()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_rand.asp) function.
2. For each row in the randomized list, assign each person a secret santa from the next row. For instance, row 1 would be assigned row 2 as his/her santa. Row 2 would be assigned row 3, and so on. Use the sql [lead()](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-lead-function/) function for this.
3. For the last row in the list, loop back around and assign the first row as his/her santa. Use the [first_value()](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-first_value-function/) function for this.

It would probably be easiest to do this in memory in your PHP application, but since this question is mostly concerned with SQL, here's a pure SQL solution. Assuming you have a table called "people" with columns "name" and "id" this will give you the result you want:

```sql
SELECT name,
(CASE
  WHEN secret_santa IS NULL
  THEN first
   ELSE secret_santa
END) secret_santa
FROM (
  SELECT name,secret_santa,(FIRST_VALUE(name) over ()) as first FROM (
    SELECT name,id,secret_santa
    FROM (
      SELECT name, id, LEAD(name) OVER (ORDER BY RAND()) secret_santa
      FROM people
    ) santas
   ) randomized
 ) wraparound
```

Output:

```
+------+--------------+
| name | secret_santa |
+------+--------------+
| Mike | Jake         |
| Jake | Bill         |
| Bill | Mike         |
+------+--------------+
```

Note, *all* of the complexity here comes from the need to wrap the last row around to the first. If you were willing to tolerate one person with no santa to be fixed with custom code, then the SQL is just:

```sql
SELECT name, LEAD(name) OVER (ORDER BY RAND()) secret_santa
FROM people
```

Output:

```
+------+--------------+
| name | secret_santa |
+------+--------------+
| Bill | Mike         |
| Mike | Jake         |
| Jake | NULL         |
+------+--------------+
```

## **[Working Example Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=39e49abebeb4d5be36453d8fbe3f5c80)**